# Global variables parse time

Tags: global-variables, loading-time

I am currently trying to debug some of the page load times on a website we host, and am running into something I find odd.
Global Variables parsing seems to be taking up half the page load time...

```
(0.977187/31.55MB) - - End Template Processing - 
(0.977237/31.55MB) - Parse Global Variables
(1.541043/36.24MB) - Template Parsing Finished
(1.547675/36.55MB) - Calling Extension Class/Method: Eedt_memory_history_ext/ee_debug_toolbar_init_settings
(1.548767/36.62MB) - Calling Extension Class/Method: Eedt_perf_alerts_ext/ee_debug_toolbar_init_settings
```

Am I correct in thinking this?

How can I reduce this time?

I feel like it shouldn't be taking half a second to parse a few variables.

#### Details

Expression Engine version: 2.10.1
PHP Version: 5.3.3

As for plugins, we don't have that many, on this page specifically, I am running a homebrewed plugin that takes in a single parameter and then queries the database and builds a response.
This was made to bypass the standard channel entries queries in EE, because with a ton of entries, it started taking a very long time.

Other addons we have (but are not running in this page) SEOLite, trunchhtml, searchfields

Comment: Are you running a lot of plugins? What version of EE and PHP?

Comment: edited for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with upgrading the version of PHP to something like 5.6 (or at least 5.4) if you can.  You should see some significant gains in loading. EllisLab put out a pretty good article [here](https://ellislab.com/blog/entry/time-to-upgrade-php) explaining this in detail. Other than that, if your site is loading slowly overall and it hasn't before you may want to check with your host.

Comment: Im not necessarily getting bad load times overall, 1.5 seconds right now.
I am debugging because that used to be around 10 seconds because we were pulling 1k+ channel entries at once in the channel entries tag. I just happened to noticed that global variables takes half a second.

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting.  Great job getting the page speed down from 10.  I've been looking through the parse order list (https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/template_engine.html) and if it's indeed the standard global variables and not including any kind of variables that may be added through plugins then that really is odd.

Comment: Ill start disabling addons and see if it affects that load time then. Its not a major concern, but if I can reduce that time, then its all the better. Thanks for confirming that its not really normal for it to be 1/3rd of the current page load.

Comment: I checked about 4 of our production sites with different ranges of content/plugins and they were all just a few ms different during global variable and template parsing times. Let me know what develops!